# File/Folder distribution

Tags: c#, svn, visualsvn

We have an SVN server configured to be able to distribute files/folders to the field via a C# application that simply performs a checkout every 2 hours to check for new items.

I think this is overkill and was wondering if there's a better solution for this with user/password protection. Also preferable, something that can show progress bar of downloads as SVN is unable to do this and you have no idea how much is left to download. The size of our repo is approx 5 GB.

Currently we use VisualSVN Server to setup the repo, TortoiseSVN to commit any changes to new files or folders we create/update and the C# app is using SharpSVN on the client PC to look and download changes.

Comment: Could this help you https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/post-commit/ ?

Comment: A fresh working copy looks like overkill compared to just updating an existing copy; not sure if that's why you mean. But displaying a progress bar implies there's a person staring at the screen—isn't it meant to be automated?

Comment: No what I mean is that we would like to move away from SVN completely. Is there a better way? Also a progress bar is more a way of showing something is happening and how long it will take, with SVN you have no idea if anything is happening or being blocked by firewall.